# Setup multiple router at home

Tags: router, lan

i'm not a network engineer. I'm just regular internet user who wants to ask couple of simple questions. Sorry if these are just basic questions.

My house already has ethernet cable installation. In 1st floor, i have 5 cables coming out from the wall , and each of these are connected to every room (2nd floor) in my house, the cables are look the same with no label, so i have no idea which cable is for room A or room B etc. Now, i want to connect my router from 1st floor to 2nd floor , i won't ask about the router setup or etc ( i can googling it) . But my question is about the hardware/tool to help me setup this network :

What tool should i buy to probe which cable is carrying the signal to room X ? i have no idea about the cost for this tool, but if it's too expensive, is there any other technique ?

I have 2 generic router for home use (4 port gigabit router) from asus and tplink. If i want to connect them , should i go for crossover or straight ? what is the rule ?

the cable coming out from the wall is quite short, so if i want to extend them i'm gonna need an female to female coupler, am i right ? straight or cross for this setup ? is there anything else should i aware of ?

Thanks

Comment: *the cable coming out from the wall is quite short* I'd recommend to use RJ-45 sockets or a wall-mounted patch-panel, and connect routers/commutators to them via patch-cords. *I have 2 generic router for home use (4 port gigabit router)* It's not enough for 5 outcoming connections (or you must to utilize one of these routers as a common switch).

Answer (score 0):

*These instructions presume all cables are in good working order. They might not be so be prepared for extended debugging if things 'don't make sense'*

So, you could buy a cable tester, which will tell you if both ends are connected, but you can easily test with some moving around (which you'd need to do anyway).

Plug all the cables into one of your routers, and then go around each room in the house - In each room, connect the other router to the cable in the room and the first router should show a light on which ever port/cable is connected - simply label them after this.

As for extending cables, yes you want female couplers, if it's ethernet cabling, and straight through cables for everything - very few things these days need cross over cables.